# How many times would I be expected to repeat an outfit?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, combinations

Imagine I own 5 bottoms, 3 tops, and 2 hats. Bottoms, tops, hats are denoted as $X_b$, $X_t$, $X_h$.

An "outfit", $X$, is defined as a particular choosing of 1 pair of bottoms, 1 top, and 1 hat.

**Question**

For a given number of days, $N$, how many times would I be expected to repeat an outfit if I picked 1 pair of bottoms, 1 top, and 1 hat at random each day?

Note: I am referring to the probability any outfit is repeated, not a particular one.

**My Work**

There are 30 outfits, since $5 *3 * 2 = 30$. Thus, for a *particular outfit* to be repeated at least once in $N$ days, that probability is the compliment of the probability this particular outfit is NOT repeated once in 30 days. In other words, we want the complement that "a given outfit is chosen, and then on $N-1$ days, some other outfit is worn.":

$$EQ1: \ 1 - [\frac{1}{30} \times (\frac{29}{30})^{N-1}] = $$

But since every outfit is equally likely, we can multiply $EQ1$ by 30:

$$EQ2: 30 \times (1 - [\frac{1}{30} \times (\frac{29}{30})^{N-1}]) = $$
$$EQ2: 30 - (\frac{29}{30})^{N-1}= $$

However, I know this is wrong because it yields a probability above 1!

Comment: Welcome to MSE.  You'll get a lot more help if you show that you have made a real effort to solve the problem yourself, even if you haven't made much progress.  What are your thoughts?  What have you tried?  How far could you get?  Where are you stuck?  This question will likely be closed if you don't add more context.  Please respond by **editing the question body.**  Clarifications don't belong in the comments.

Comment: You have $30$ possible outfits, so you would be expected to repeat an outfit around once a month. Also, refrain from overcomplicating your question, you used variables in places you didn't need to, usually, it's the answerer that needs to make variables for his own usage to solve the problem, the question would've been much simpler without you including them. Nevertheless, as the former commenter has said: welcome to MSE.

Comment: "Once a month" means $1$ out of $30$ days.

Comment: @Sdavid552 Depends on what the OP intended by the phrase "*repeat an outfit*".  If the intent is that there is one particular outfit in mind, then I agree with your comment.  If not, then I think that variables may be needed.  Although I can not personally guarantee that [Linearity of Expectation](https://brilliant.org/wiki/linearity-of-expectation/) is valid here, this problem seems similar to other mathSE problems where other mathSE reviewers have indicated that the approach would be valid.  ...see next comment

Comment: If your intent is whether **any** outfit is repeated, and if in fact Linearity of Expectation is valid, then I would recommend that approach.  Personally, I would have to study probability theory for some time before I could form an opinion on whether Linearity of Expectation is a valid approach for this problem.

Comment: I updated it and added some of my own work

Comment: You need to carefully define what you are counting.  You clearly want to count an outfit that is worn twice as one event of repeating an outfit.  How about one that is worn three times?  Is that two repeats, or three repeats, one for the second wearing and two for the third because it has been worn twice before?

Comment: If an outfit is repeated 3 times that only counts as a single event occurrence begin the event is that "an outfit is repeated"; I don't care how many times it's repeated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your EQ1 is wrong.  You also need to subtract the chance that the outfit is never worn because then that outfit is not repeated.  You also need a factor $N$ for the number of days you could have worn it in the term for wearing it once.  So the chance a particular outfit is not repeated is
$$1-\left(\frac {29}{30}\right)^{N}-N\cdot\frac 1{30}\left(\frac {29}{30}\right)^{N-1}$$
For $N=30$ this gives about $0.2642$ chance a given outfit is not repeated.  You can use linearity of expectation to get an expected number of outfits repeated at least once of almost $8$.  You expect about $11$ outfits never to have been worn and another $11$ to have been worn once each.

To get the chance that no outfit is repeated, you have $30$ choices the first day to avoid a repeat, $29$ the next day, and so on.  The total chance is $0$ if $N \gt 30$, otherwise it is
$$\frac {30!}{30^N(30-N)!}$$
for $N=30$ this comes out about $1.288 \cdot 10^{-12}$

Answer (score 0):

Being as don't care about multiple repeats, then you can use the Inclusion Exclusion principle.  See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle.

Say $N=3$.  On the second day there is a 1/30 chance you had a repeat.  On the third day, there is a $1/30$ chance you had a repeat of either day 1 or day 2, but then there's a chance that day 1 and day 2 are repeats of each other, thus the chance of a new repeat on day 3 is $1/30 + 1/30 - (1/30)^2$.  I believe the formula you want is then
$$
\sum_{i=1}^{N-1} \sum_{k=1}^i (-1)^{k+1}\binom{i}{k}\left(\frac{1}{30}\right)^k.
$$
Of course, this formula is not valid once the double sum passes 30.